why that is receive "Your session crashed. Automatically restarting." at Google-Colab whereas I am using GPU
I want to read a camera with cv2.
This is my code:
import cv2 as cv

cv.namedWindow('mah Window', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)

source = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
  ret, frame = source.read()
  if not ret:
    break
  if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
    break

sorce.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()

when I run this I receive:

Your session crashed. Automatically restarting.


Your session restarted after a crash. Diagnosing...


Your session crashed for an unknown reason. View runtime logs

(View runtime logs) is a link to a table with some date and time

What is sorce? Shouldn't it be source.release()?

@SoftwareDveloper that'll be a mere NameError. it's irrelevant because OP's issue happens before that.

Colab is not your own computer. Colab is a Google server.
You can't have namedWindow or imshow or waitKey in Colab. The Colab server has no display attached to it.
You can't have VideoCapture in Colab. There is no webcam attached to the Google server.
